# How to access ajax get call params in express route

Tags: javascript, ajax, express, parameters

I have this ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/topics/test",
    type: "GET",
    data: {
        topics: getIds
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr){
        console.log(xhr);
    }
});
```

And I also have this express route:

```
router.get("topics/test?", function(req, res){
  console.log(req.params);
  res.json(req.params.topics);
});
```

`req.params` is empty.
I tried using `req.params.topics` but it says its undefined.

So how do I access the param data in the express route?

Comment: What do you see in network tab of your browser? What is the url in the broswer network it shows?

Comment: @ArupRakshit It shows **http://localhost:8080/topics/test?topics%5B%5D=5b58b042ac3cf43730ec9b03&topics%5B%5D=5b58b042ac3cf43730ec9b0c&topics%5B%5D=5b58b042ac3cf43730ec9b02&topics%5B%5D=5b58b042ac3cf43730ec9b08&topics%5B%5D=5b58b042ac3cf43730ec9b06&topics%5B%5D=5b5666f0fd8d0b0b085fda6d**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery GET request, converts the data value to a query string. So please use `req.query.topics`.

```
router.get("topics/test", function(req, res){
  console.log(req.query);
  res.json(req.query.topics);
});
```

Checkout [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query).